# Linux Kernel 5.15.1, fstab umask=0022, mount command shows fmask=37777600022,dmask=37777600022

Tags: linux, mount, ntfs, fstab, umask

I downloaded and compiled the `linux-cacule` (5.15 for native `ntfs3` support) kernel from the [AUR repo](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/linux-cacule/). Following the documentation here on the new `ntfs3` mount option:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ntfs3.html

You can specify the `umask` (files and directories) or `fmask` and `dmask` separately. I have an `NTFS` partition on one of my drives which is being mounted via `UUID` in my `/etc/fstab` file like so:

```
UUID=B29AC1289AC0EA45          /Windows8_OS   ntfs3 ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,nohidden,sys_immutable,acl,uhelper=udisks2,umask=0022,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,user 0 0
```

You'll notice that my `umask` specifies 0022, which should result in 0755 for directories and 0644 for files. However, when I run the `mount` command, this is what my output shows:

```
/dev/sda5 on /Windows8_OS type ntfs3 (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=37777600022,dmask=37777600022,iocharset=utf8,sys_immutable,nohidden,acl,uhelper=udisks2,user)
```

What are these `fmask` and `dmask` values? Does it not matter since I'm mounting the partition as `ro`?

I tried manually mounting another `NTFS` partition from `/dev/sda7` with the following command:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs3 -o rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,nohidden,sys_immutable,acl,uhelper=udisks2,umask=0022,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,user /dev/sda7 /home/user/test
```

and after it successfully mounted, I ran the `mount` again and it displayed the same long number for `fmask` and `dmask`. I traversed into `/home/user/test` and typed `touch hi` and that worked just fine and the file perm was 644.

I even tried remounting but with `umask=022` instead to see if that would have made a difference, but the subsequent `mount` indicated the same long values. I then tried remounting again but instead of `umask`, I specified `fmask=022,dmask=022` but after it mounted, the `mount` showed the same long integer. I tried googling for the string `fmask=37777600022` but couldn't find anything.

Anyone have any insight into this?